# How do I get the surface area of vtkUnstructuredGrid

Tags: vtk

I neel get surface area of `vtkUnstructuredGrid`, and `vtkTriangleFilter` is used to process `VTKUnstructuredgrid`, and then `vtkMassProperties` is used to get the surface area, but the obtained area is 0.

Here is my code, The following is my code, after running the prompt

```
Input port 0 of algorithm vtkTriangleFilter(000002CF5EAEB670) has 0 connections but is not optional.
```

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> pointCoordinates;
    // Face 1
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 2, 0} });  // Node 0
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 2, 3} });  // Node 1
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 0, 3} });  // Node 2
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 0, 0} });  // Node 3
    // Face 2
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 2, 0} });  // Node 4
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 1, 0} });  // Node 5
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 1, 3} });  // Node 6
    pointCoordinates.push_back({ {0, 2, 3} });  // Node 7

    // Create the points.
    vtkNew<vtkPoints> points;

    for (auto i = 0; i < pointCoordinates.size(); ++i)
    {
        points->InsertNextPoint(pointCoordinates[i].data());
    }

    vtkNew<vtkUnstructuredGrid> uGrid;
    uGrid->SetPoints(points);

    vtkIdType ptid[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3};
    uGrid->InsertNextCell(VTK_QUAD, 4, ptid);
    vtkIdType ptid2[4] = { 4, 5, 6, 7};
    uGrid->InsertNextCell(VTK_QUAD, 4, ptid2);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputData(uGrid);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>  pd =
    vtkPolyData::SafeDownCast(mapper->GetInput());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter> filter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter>::New();
    filter->SetInputData(pd);
    filter->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMassProperties> m_pvtkMassProperties =
        vtkMassProperties::New();
    m_pvtkMassProperties->SetInputData(filter->GetOutput());
    m_pvtkMassProperties->Update();
    double area = m_pvtkMassProperties->GetSurfaceArea();
    std::cout << area << std::endl;
```